# Traffic Management Solution for Azure App Services not relying on DNS

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-traffic-manager

At the moment, we are using Azure Traffic Management to provide Load Balancing and High Availability across multiple regions for Azure App Services deployed on App Service Environments. We have reduced the Traffic Manager TTL to 30 secs. However, some of the clients have DNS cache (4 hours TTL) which we cannot control and this impacts the availability of our solution.

What would be a good alternative to provide HA and LB to Azure App Services which does not rely on DNS? We have seen on the documentation that MS suggests third-party solutions, but are there any particular suggestions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

As you point out, Azure Traffic Manager operates in the DNS layer. If you are looking at managing multiple endpoints for high availability and load balancing outside of DNS layer, I would recommend considering [Azure Application Gateway](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-gateway/) (for HTTP workloads) and / or [Azure Load Balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-overview) (for any layer 4 (TCP, UDP) load balancing).

You may also find this article on [Combining Load Balancers in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-load-balancing-azure) relevant for your use case

Comment: Hi Dilip. We have all our web apps on PaaS, so Azure Load Balancer is not an option. I haven't seen Azure App Gateway recommended for **high availability across regions**. Is this supported/recommended?